# Special Character not allowed in input textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to restrict special characters in my textbox. I restricted
Characters. But not the special character. I have pasted the code
which am trying.

```
<input type="text" name="" class="zip zipCode">
```

```js
var $currentZip;

// Override WM enter key event
$(".zipCode").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $currentZip = $(this)
        zipUrl($currentZip)
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        // Let it happen, don't do anything
    } else {
        // Make sure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 && event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
            console.log("Keycode :"+ event.keyCode)
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > 5)
        $this.val($this.val().substr(0, 5))
});

$('.zipSubmit').on('click', function() {
    $currentZip = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.zipCode')
    console.log($currentZip.attr('type'))
    zipUrl($currentZip);
});
```

Comment: Depending on which characters you want to allow it would probably easier to just use a regular expression. Have a search for input masking. There's literally thousand of tutorials, libraries and questions about this subject.

Comment: I found an answer. But if I type it in ipad or in android devices it's typing. How do I restrict in device oriented ?